# Additivity of the union of Lebesgue measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-measure

Please help me with this!! I dont have any idea how to use the information given in the hypothesis:

If $(A_{n})_{n\ge 1}$ is a family of measurable Lebesgue sets, with $\lambda(A_{n}\cap A_{m})=0$, for every $m\neq n$, then$$\lambda (\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_{n})=\sum_{n\ge 1}\lambda(A_{n}  ) $$.
We know that the member on the left is smaller that the member in the right,but I dont know how to show the reverse inequality.($\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure)

Comment: Can you write out the definition of $\lambda$?

Comment: @T.B, presumably, $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure. Do you want OP to write out the definition of Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, because then perhaps it will highlight what issue the OP is having in proving the theorem. As it stands, I don't know where they are having an issue, or whether they have any background results that are applicable.

Comment: @GerryMyerson there is more than one way to do that. So without knowing how the OP did that, the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ahmed, I was assuming OP was asking a question about Lebesgue measure on the real line. Sure, there's more than one way to write out the definition, but there's only one Lebesgue measure on the real line.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True - but whether the definition is given via outer measures and covers or as a result of Riesz representation makes the proof quite different.

Comment: @T.Bongers: I actually don't see where the definition of the Lebesgue measure comes into play. Just the definition of a measure and $\sigma$-additivity.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm guessing that the OP has not yet proven that $\lambda$ defines a measure, and needs to complete this step in order to know it's $\sigma$-additive - otherwise the question is rather trivial.

Answer (score 1):

First we prove that for disjoint set $A_n$, there is
$$
\lambda(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(A_n)\tag1
$$
We only need to prove that
$$
\lambda(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) \geqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(A_n)\tag{1'}
$$
as another case is implied in the sub-additivity of Lebesgue measure.

We use Caratheodory measure for Lebesgue measurable set, i.e. $A$ is Lebesgue measurable iff for any $E\subset X$, there is
$$
\lambda(E)=\lambda(A\cap E)+\lambda(A^c\cap E)\tag2
$$
First we prove that if $A_1, A_2$ are Lebesgue measurable and disjoint, then 
$$
\lambda(A_1\cup A_2)=\lambda(A_1)+\lambda(A_2)\tag3
$$
Let $E= A_1\cup A_2$ and $A_1\cap A_2=\varnothing$. By $(2)$, we have
\begin{align}
\lambda(A_1\cup A_2)&=\lambda((A_1\cup A_2)\cap A_1)+\lambda((A_1\cup A_2)\cap A_1^c)
\\
&=\lambda(A_1)+\lambda((A_1\cap A_1^c)\cup (A_2\cap A_1^c))
\\
&=\lambda(A_1)+\lambda(A_2\cap A_1^c)
\\
&=\lambda(A_1)+\lambda(A_2)
\end{align}

Next we prove 
$$
A_1\subset A_2\implies \lambda(A_1)\leqslant \lambda(A_2)\tag{4}
$$
Clearly if $A_1\subset A_2$,  then $A_2=A_1\cup(A_2-A_1)$. So $(4)$ follows from $(3)$ and $\lambda(A_2-A_1)\geqslant0$.

Finally for any disjoint $A_n$, since 
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^m A_n \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$$
By $(3)$ and $(4)$, there is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^m\lambda(A_n)=\lambda(\bigcup_{n=1}^m A_n)\leqslant \lambda(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n)
$$
Let $m\to\infty$, $(1')$ is proved, and $(1)$ follows.

**Edit:**

Next if for any $\:n\ne m$, $\lambda(A_n\cap A_m)=0$, let 
$$
B_n=\cases{ A_n-\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}(A_k\cap A_n), \quad n>1
\\ A_1, \quad n=1
}
$$
Clearly for any $\:n\ne m$, $B_n\cap B_m=\varnothing$, and also 
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n\tag5
$$
Since $A_k\cap A_n\subset A_n$, there is $\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}(A_k\cap A_n)\subset A_n$. So
$$
\lambda(B_n)=\lambda(A_n)-\lambda\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}(A_k\cap A_n)\right)
$$
And since
$$
\lambda\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}(A_k\cap A_n)\right)\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\lambda(A_k\cap A_n)=0
$$
We have
$$
\lambda\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{n-1}(A_k\cap A_n)\right)=0\quad\text{and }\quad \lambda(B_n)=\lambda(A_n)
$$
So by $(1)$ and $(5)$
$$
\lambda(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n)=\lambda(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(B_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(A_n)
$$

Comment: I dont understand something...where do you use that $\lamda(A_{n}\cap A_{m})=0$, for every $m\neq n$? I dont think that implies that $A_{n}\cap A_{m}$ is an empty set.

Comment: Why if $\lambda(A_{n}\cap A_{m})=0$, $A_{n}$ and $A_{m}$ are disjoint sets?

Comment: It is clear that, from the property of the countable subaditivity of the Lebesgue measure, that we have $\lambda(\bigcup_{n\ge 1}A_{n} \le\ \sum \lambda(A_{n}$..I dont know how to use the information given to prove the reverse ineguality..$A_{n}$ and $A_{m}$ are not disjoint sets...the Lebesgue measure of their intersection is $0$, for $m \neq n$.

Answer (score 0):

1. For every non-empty open $S\subset R$ there is a unique countable (i.e.finite or countably infinite) family $S^*$ of pair-wise disjoint, non-empty open intervals such that $\cup S^*=S.$ (Open half-lines are also open intervals here.) And $\lambda (S)=\sum_{s\in S^*} \lambda (s).$ Applying this to a finite family $F$ of pair-wise disjoint open sets we see that $\lambda (\cup F)=\sum_{f\in F} \lambda (f).$
2. Let $G=\{G_1,...,G_n\}$ be a finite family of pair-wise disjoint closed sets. There is a finite family $G'=\{G'_1,...,G'_n\}$ of pair-wise disjoint open sets such that $G_1\subset G'_i$ for $i=1,...,n$. For any $r>0$ let $S$ be an open set with $\cup G\subset S$ and $\lambda (S)<r+\lambda (\cup G).$ Now since $\cup G\subset (S\cap (\cup G'))=\cup_{j=1}^n(S\cap G'_j)$ and since $\{S\cap G_j :j=1,...,n\}$ is a pair-wise disjoint finite open family, we have $$\sum_1^n \lambda (G_n)\leq \sum_1^n \lambda (S\cap G'_n)=\lambda (\cup_1^n (S\cap G'_n)=\lambda (S\cap (\cup G')\leq \lambda (S)\leq r+\lambda (\cup G).$$ Therefore $\sum_{g\in G}\lambda (g)\leq r+ \lambda (\cup G).$ Since this holds for all $r>0$ and since $\sum_{g\in G}\lambda (g)\geq \lambda (\cup G),$ we have  $\sum_{g\in G}\lambda (g)=\lambda (\cup G). $
3. Let H be a finite family of pairwise-disjoint measurable sets  with $n$ members $(n>0)$. For any $r>0,$ for each $h\in H,$ let $h_c \subset h$ where $h_c$ is closed and $\lambda (h)\leq r/n+\lambda (h_c).$ Then $$\lambda (\cup H)\geq \lambda (\cup_{h\in H}h_c)=\sum{h\in H}\lambda (h_c)\geq r+\sum{h\in H}\lambda (h).$$  Therefore $\lambda (\cup H)\geq r+\sum{h\in H}\lambda (h). $ Since this holds for all $r>0,$ and $\lambda (\cup H)\leq \sum_{h\in H}\lambda (h).$ Therefore $\lambda (\cup H)=\sum{h\in H}\lambda (h). $
4. Let $A=\{A_n :n\in N\}$ be a family of measurable sets such that $m\neq n\implies A_m\cap A_n=\phi.$ For all $ k\in N$ we have $\lambda (\cap A)\geq \lambda (\cap_{n=1}^k A_j)=\sum_{n=1}^k \lambda (A_n).$ Therefore $$\lambda (\cup A)\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda (A_n).$$ ....................................... 5. A countable union of measure-$0$ sets is measure-$0$, for if $U_n$ is open with $U_n\supset B_n$ and $\lambda (U_n)< 2^{-n}\epsilon$ then $\cup_nU_n\supset \cup_n B_n$ and $\lambda (\cup_nU_n)\leq \sum_n\lambda (U_n)<\epsilon.$ Suppose for a measurable family $A_n :n\in N$ we have $m\ne n\to \lambda (A_m\cap A_n)=0$.For each $n$ let $B_n=\cup_{m\ne n}(A_m\cap A_n)$ and $A'_n=A_n\backslash B_n$.Then $\lambda (A_n)=\lambda (A'_n)+\lambda (B_n)=\lambda (A'_n)+0=\lambda (A'_n).$ Now $\{A'_n :n\in N\}$ is a pair-wise disjoint measurable family. Since $\lambda (\cup_nB_n)=0$ we have $\sum_n \lambda (A_n)=\sum_n\lambda (A'_n)=\lambda (\cup_n A'_n)=\lambda((\cup_nA'_n)\cup (\cup_n B_n))=\lambda (\cup_n(A'_n\cup B_n))=\lambda (\cup_n A_n).$

Comment: i would appreciate it if somebody would edit this for better display.

Comment: why if $\lambda(A_{n}\cap A_{m}=0$, $A_{m}$ and $A_{n}$ are disjoint sets?

Comment: I didn't say that.But I forgot to enter part 5.